# Incorporate Membership in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been wondering on how to use ASP.NET Membership together with MVC. The basic setup is very simple, but if I want to use extra fields like address, nickname etc, should I then use ProfileCommon or should I create a separate table which contains the extra data and link to the UserId in Aspnet_users?

I have an issue where I have changed the name in Membership to use the email, and I then need the extra fields (address, nickname etc.). If I use ProfileCommon I can receive the object by

```
 public static ProfileCommon GetProfile(string username)
        {
            return ((ProfileCommon)(ProfileBase.Create(username)));
        }
```

The problem is I save the UserId in different tables, and I can't figure out how to receive the ProfileCommon object by UserId instead of username (which in my case is the email)?

I could then either change the relation in the different tables to use the email, but this would be a very slow implementation, or I could create a separate table with the extra fields.

Is there perhaps a third and better option?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC runs on ASP.NET so you achieve this the same way you would in a normal ASP.NET WebForms application.

Comment: I have removed EF 4.0 tag because there is no problem targeting Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to create the separate table, since I would not be limited by the ProfileBase class.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply join the user table in order to receive the email.

Generally it does not seem to be a good idea to use two different fields as the id.